# Safari: stop hiding tabs

Tags: safari, google-chrome, tabs

I can't use safari and continue using chrome only because of 1 reason:
chrome doesn't hides tabs (when there are too many of them)
I just want to act safari like this
[image: Good tabs]

And not like this

[image: Bad tabs]

Is there some plugin or workaround to make safari better ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Glims for Safari](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27708/glims) is your friend.

After installation go to Safari > Preferences > Glims > Tabs Misc.  and check "Set minimum tab labels size to favicon size".

You'll get something like this…

[image: Lots of tabs]