# Is it possible to scroll the tabs in Safari if there are too many like Firefox?

Tags: macos, safari

When I open a lot of tabs in safari it shows the first ones normally and all those, which do not fit a grouped into one tab. This is very annoying when switching between tabs that are at the end.

Is it possible to make them scrollable as it is done in Firefox?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108668/is-there-a-shortcut-to-change-tabs-on-safari

Comment: i don't want it to be done by a shortcut, but thanks for the hint

Comment: For those of us who are not familiar to this.  Can you provide details of how you achieve this in Firefox. I.e what input device is used, actual behaviour and is it standard to Firefox or an add on. Thanks

Comment: no add-on or anything is needed, it's the standard behavior in firefox. Basically image the tabs being in a horizontally scrollable element, with the scroll-element having the width of the safari-window

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the latest version of Safari, you can pinch in on a trackpad to reveal all of your tabs. You can swipe through this list using two fingers or by clicking on the dots below the previews.

[image: Scrollable Tabs in Safari]

Comment: Thanks, but this still only changes the active tab, I would like to have those tabes in view that I am currently using

Answer (score 1):

I would probably wait until Yosimite ships. During the WWDC Safari demo one of the things shown was how you could scroll "quickly" through a large amount of tabs. I usually prefer native solution than add-ons anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer to [this similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60903/safari-stop-hiding-tabs/61094#61094). It suggests using [Glims](https://web.archive.org/web/20171230053024/http://machangout.com:80/tutorials/general) which, whilst it won't allow you to scroll tabs, it does allow you to set the minimum tab size to the favicon size, which allows you to have many more tabs open at once without the grouping behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Apple announced that this will be a future feature in Safari when Yosemite ships. There's not any clear indication of older OS will get the newer safari, but that has happened most of the time in the recent past.

http://www.theverge.com/2014/6/2/5765048/apple-wwdc-2014-os-x-yosemite-ios-8-and-all-the-news-you-need-to-know

Answer (score 0):

When you have too many tabs to fit in the Safari window, click the chevrons »

You will see a local menu listing the remaining tabs.

*Note :* Contrary to Firefox, this menu does not list all the tabs of the window. It lists the last visible tab and the invisible tabs.

For another look, see also the answer by @alexsmbaratti